# MarkdownPreview in Sublime-text3 opens Signal app, instead of browser tab

Tags: sublime-text-3, markdown

I installed the [MarkdownPreview package](https://github.com/facelessuser/MarkdownPreview/) in `Sublime Text3` with no trouble.
When I try to generate a preview of my markdown file in a browser following [these](https://facelessuser.github.io/MarkdownPreview/usage/) instructions, the system opens my Signal messenger app, instead of a tab in the browser.

Any idea if this is an issue with my configuration?
I'm running Ubuntu 18.04LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. The root cause for me was that Signal was set to be the default application to open files with the `.html` extension. My fix was to locate a file with the `.html` extension in the File browser. Right-click and select "Properties." Select the "Open With" tab and select a more appropriate application (e.g., Firefox or Chrome). Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked perfect!